# How to find out that RSS feed is updated?

Tags: android, xml, rss

I have to write an Android RSS reader. Before start, I have some questions and I'll be glad if you help me to find the answers:

1. Assume that RSS XML file contains 10 last items. If I could go
   deeper and load more items, what should I do?
2. How to know that
   RSS feed is updated? Is checking feed periodically the only way?
3. Assume that RSS XML file contains 10 last items and I get all of
   them. The next time I check the RSS feed, two new items is added to
   RSS feed. Now RSS XML contains items 2-12. This means that I have
   downloaded 8 items twice. Is there a way to prevent this and query
   for only new items?